# Some zip files not unarchiving in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am downloading a zip file from an API and trying to unzip it using Python shutil.

```
shutil.unpack_archive(file_name)
```

It gives weird behaviour, for some files it works, for others it shows the following error:

> name.zip is not a zip file

There is no issue with the downloaded file, I am able to unarchive it manually.
Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you using? can you unzip these files using unzipping tools such as `unzip` on linux with `subprocess.check_output(["unzip", path])` ?

Comment: @BijayRegmi  am on windows :(

Comment: On windows 10 you can use `tar`, just modify the command to `subprocess.check_output(["tar","-xf", path])`

Comment: @BijayRegmi
`subprocess.check_output(["tar","-xf", "file.zip"])`
It runs but there is no output on console or unzipped file in the location, or I am missing something?

Comment: to get output you need to store output of opened subprocess or print it. Try to unzip the problematic file in windows cmd with tar, that might help understand what is happening. It is not easy to say without the sample file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) (for zip archives) or [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) (for tar archives)